# Client side pagination not showing with Smart Table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, smart-table

**Problem**

Data are loaded asynchronously and displayed correctly, but pagination does not appear. Thank you if you can help.

**HTML**

```
<table st-safe-src="update" st-table="displayedItemList" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field1</th>
            <th>Field2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in displayedItemList">
            <td>{{item.Field1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Field2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $scope.itemList = [];
    $scope.displayedItemList = [];
    $scope.update = 0;

    $scope.initialize = function ()
    {
        var d = new $.Deferred();

        itemService.getItems().then(function (data) {
            $scope.itemList = data;
            $scope.displayedItemList = [].concat($scope.itemList);
            $scope.update++;
            d.resolve();
        });

        return d;
    }
```

**Alternative tried**

... same result.

```
    <table st-safe-src="itemList" ...
```

Comment: if you have only one page in your dataset, the pagination will not show. how many items itemList does have ?

Comment: 43 items. I think the problem is with the async aspect. But I switched back from Smart Table to Angular UI Grid for wich one of my colleagues already had draft code (and doesn't display pagination either).

Answer (score 0):

in the controller, you need to fill in the `st-safe-src` (update), not `displayedItemList.` 
I mean, for example

```
$scope.update = $scope.itemList;
```